# Powershell automatin, license serial validation, advanced installer

Tags: powershell, automation, advanced-installer

**Powershell automation, license serial validation types selection and configuration**

I'm not able to find a Component that can be used to enable and select serial validation type.

Is there no such interface for PowerShell automation?

Comment: You might need to provide a bit more background on what you're trying to achieve,  and show any code you've already written. For example , "license serial validation" for *what*? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some more guidance on asking questions.

Comment: That's a rarely used scenario. Most of the times our user just enable the serial validation from the GUI and that is it.

What scenario exactly are you trying to automate?

p.s. I work on the Advanced Installer team